# Eclipse: Installing Aptana Studio with EGit

Tags: eclipse, aptana

I am trying to install Aptana 3 as a plugin to Eclipse Helios SR2. I am getting an Error which informs me that GIT cannot be located and that I should either install portable git or browse to the root directory of my GIT install.

I have installed the EGIT plugin (1.0.0.XX) which is working. But I cannot find the root directory of this GIT install. Could some one point out where it should be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That dialog is looking for a command-line version of Git for three purposes:

1. Enable the scripting/commands infrastructure to download new plugins
2. Allow the terminal view to work
3. Enable git support in the IDE

Since you are already using EGit, #3 isn't important, but unfortunately even if you could point to EGit from that dialog, it would not enable terminal support. My suggestion is to install PortableGit--it's small, self contained (it's stored inside the workspace), and unobtrusive.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, the plugin gives you the ability to install portablegit from the same error dialog, and I guess I'll just do that as you suggested.